# The phrase "get real work done"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Recently I heard about this phrase "get real work done", and I am wondering what are the major (THREE examples is good enough) contexts where one says "get real work done"?

Comment: Too broad to answer. It could be anything! **FROM** I hired a sharp-shooter to kill Alex. He just wounded him and asking for money. I'll say, "Get real work done and I'll pay you" **TO** "Whatever works with ipad, people trying to tell us they can get real work done on an ipad is really just a bad joke" :P

Comment: But to help you - get real work done means doing the work that something/someone is expected to do and not just wandering around.

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed. This is an expression used in specific situations, as the answer by @TRomano and perhaps especially by the comment by **apsillers**. There is work and then there is "real work."

Answer (score 2):

You can use that phrase in any context where previous efforts are felt to lack efficacy, and something has changed that will help to complete the task.

Depending on the the context, the implication can be that people assigned to the task have been slacking off, or they could merely be inexpert, or not strong enough, or lacking the proper equipment, or too few in number, etc.

Now that Kurt is driving the new tractor, we can get some real work done.

Now that Kurt is helping us to paint the room, we can get some real work done.

Now that that jokester Kurt has gone, we can get some real work done.

Comment: I might also suggest, "Now that the house's floor plan is finished, we can get some real work done and actually build the house." Here, mental "planning work" is distinguished from hands-on "real work".

Comment: Or you do part of a project, which involves preliminary labor, and then you have an additional step or steps that involves more labor *or* labor that more closely involves the actual goal of the project.